# How to build an Ionic app without the scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, mobile

I am building an Ionic app, but once the page is getting bigger, the app presents an scroll, there is any way to remove the scroll and let the app more native like?

My code has only 2 slides with some products description and category.

Comment: You're saying you want to disable scrolling? Or just that a scrollbar is visible and you want to hide it but keep the ability to scroll?

Comment: Second option. The ability to scroll is necessary, I Just want to hide it.

Comment: In what environment are you seeing the scrollbar? a web browser? iOS simulator? Android Emulator?

Comment: Ionic lab when I launch the app with serve -l

Comment: The Ionic Lab that's been sunsetted since 2016? https://lab.ionic.io/

Comment: seems to be active - https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/previewing
any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ionic Lab" is a deprecated desktop application, [sunsetted in 2016](https://lab.ionic.io/). the Ionic CLI command ["ionic serve"](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/previewing#run-locally-in-a-web-browser) lets you serve the app locally in a browser. So it appears you're previewing your application in a web browser. When doing this, it's not going to appear or behave exactly as it will on a real mobile device. If you [run a build, open your app in Xcode and test in the iOS simulator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios), you'll most likely see that no scrollbar is visible.

Testing locally in a browser with `ionic serve` is very practical and useful but the preview should not be believed to be a 100% accurate native preview.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clearly explanation, Wesley. I will try do simulate using other tool.